# How is this special paper for calligraphic works called in Chinese? And what is it originally made of?

Tags: expressions, terminology, calligraphy, handwriting

Just to check with experts, I know the terms 宣纸、米字格、田字格、薄纸等等 for special paper used for calligraphic works.

But how would you call a
paper as shown on the screenshot from Temu.

The description in Temu is not very helpful as it names all technical terms pars pro toto for one thing and leaves open what kind of paper it actually is, if this paper is made out of (some sort of imitation of) animal skin...

How would you call such a paper used for calligraphic works in Chinese? And what kind of material is it originally made of?

While 羊皮纸 seems inappropriate, there's still the term 蝉纸 offered by the dictionary.

Maybe, you can double check on 拼多多 how the analogous product is advertised...

[image: Screenshot from Temu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched on 淘宝Taobao and 拼多多Pinduoduo，there are no products that directly use the same image， but there are some related products.

蝉纸 is a right word. This 蝉纸 means "蝉翼宣纸". It is not really made of insect wings， but just a description, indicating that it is very light and very thin, like cicada wings.

This kind of paper is 白棉纸, and its raw material is the bark of 构树 Broussonetia papyrifera. In this picture, you can see two traces on the right side of the paper. These are the traces of the clips. The color of the paper is made by dipping it with dye and then drying it.

This kind of paper is widely used. The buyer and seller information I saw on Taobao shows that it can be used to package Chinese liquor （like Moutai）, calligraphy (Buyer comments: it is very suitable for writing 小行书 、草书 and 小楷), and draw ink paintings.

These words are related words to find this kind of paper （summed up in a large number of product titles）:
茅台酒包装纸、裹酒纸、做旧仿古酱色宣纸、酱香纸、蝉翼皮纸

[image]